# Singin is not a function react context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-context

I'm trying to build a function that will makes the login context in react using typescript. The IDE says no errors, however, when trying to run the function, it gives me this error `Erro ao autenticar: TypeError: singIn is not a function`.

Here is my code for the page:

```js
    const { singIn, user } = useAuth();

    async function handleLogin(event: FormEvent){
        event.preventDefault();

        if(!user){
            try {
                await singIn(email, password);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error("Erro ao autenticar: "+err)
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Here is my code for the auth:

```js
type User = {
    email: string;
    name: string;
    password: string;
}

type AuthContextType = {
    user: User | undefined;
    singIn: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
    singOut: () => Promise<void>
  
}

type AuthProvider = {
    children: ReactNode
}

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextType);

export function AuthProvider(props: AuthProvider){
    const [ user, setUser ] = useState<User>();
    const [ emailTry, setEmailTry ] = useState("");
    const { userGet } = useGetUser(emailTry);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    async function singIn(email: string, password: string) {
        //Code to authenticate
    }

    async function singOut() {
        //Code to Logout
    }

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, singIn, singOut}}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Any idea about how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are involving your App with the `AuthContext`. See in my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";

import Routes from "./routes";
import history from "./routes/history";

import { AuthProvider } from "./context";

import Theme from './theme';

import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
      <AuthProvider> {/* here I'm doing that with my AuthProvider */}
        <Router history={history}>
          <Routes />
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you do not do that with the Context, the functions from Context turn into not recognized functions for the other components.